# Get a string between the 2nd and 3rd instances of a known string

Tags: t-sql, substring, charindex

Given the string `'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc$ddddd'`, I need to get the value between the 2nd and third `$`. I.e. `ccccc`.

There was an SO question that gave me a good starting point, but I'm not quite there. (So sorry, I had the page for the question, did some more searching and then lost it in my history. Otherwise I would've included a link to that question.)

The OP in that question needed to get `bbbbb` from `aaaa$bbbbb$ccccc`. The answer was this code:

`SELECT SUBSTRING('aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc', CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc') + 1, CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc', CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc') + 1) - CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc') - 1) as My_String`

I worked it out to this current code:

`SUBSTRING('aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc$ddddd', CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc$ddddd') + 1, CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc$ddddd', CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc$ddddd') + 1 + CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc$ddddd') + 1) - CHARINDEX('$', 'aaaaa$bbbbb$ccccc$ddddd') - 1) as My_String`

Which is returning `bbbbb$ccccc`

So I figure I don't have either the second `CHARINDEX()` or the `CHARINDEX()` in the subtraction part of the `SUBSTRING()` corret.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @PatrickHurst, sorry - this is in ADW

Comment: can you post the result of running `SELECT @@VERSION` ?

Comment: Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.20438.0 Jan 10 2023 20:57:20 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much simpler if you treat it as a string split:

```
SELECT value
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string,'$',1)
 WHERE ordinal = 3
```

If you must do it as string manipulation you can use:

```
SELECT @string, 
CHARINDEX('$',@string, CHARINDEX('$',@string)+1) AS SecondOccurrence Position,
CHARINDEX('$',@string,CHARINDEX('$',@string, CHARINDEX('$',@string)+1)+1) AS ThirdOccurrence Position,
SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('$',@string, CHARINDEX('$',@string)+1)+1,CHARINDEX('$',@string,CHARINDEX('$',@string, CHARINDEX('$',@string)+1)+1)-CHARINDEX('$',@string, CHARINDEX('$',@string)+1)-1)
```

What we're doing here is finding the second occurrence, using CHARINDEX with the optional third parameter of Start Position, and providing the position of the first occurrence. Then we do the same thing again, with the composite CHARINDEX providing the position of the second occurrence as the start position.
Now we know both positions, we can use them with `SUBSTRING` to provide a start position (first occurrence position +1) and a length (third occurrence - second occurrence).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I punched that into my table query and it worked like a charm. I knew it was a matter of getting the correct CHARINDEX values to do the "math" with for the SUBSTRING function, breaking it down like you did, but wasn't able to quite get there..